# Google Calendar API V3 insert recurring event default timezone

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

Looks like there is a bit of inconsistency between 2 ways calendar ***RECURRING*** events could be created using the ***TIME ZONE***:

1. **'quickAdd'** - does not require you to provide a timezone. The Calendar's default (UTC) or the one set by the Calendar owner will be used. Fair enough.
2. **'insert'** - the API doc states: "For recurring events this field is required and specifies the time zone in which the recurrence is expanded. For single events this field is optional and indicates a custom time zone for the event start/end."

Why for **'insert'**-ing recurring events we cannot use use the time zone the Calendar already have? 
The **'quickAdd'** api endpoint clearly shows that it is possible!

For example, if you call the quickAdd with the following text (**Important meeting at Office at 11am-11:25am every Fri with John**) recurring events will be created with the time zone that already set in the Calendar!

Sure thing that I could get the Calendar time zone from the settings (/calendar/v3/users/me/settings/timezone). But this will require one extra call. It will cause more latency and bring more complexity to the code.

Another issue. The **quickAdd** api call for recurring events creates not only recurring events but also the same event on the day when the call been made! The API doc does not provide any explanation what are the correct values for the **text** attribute.

Would be great to hear back from Google API team to clarify those things.
Thank you.